# Connect React/AJAX to custom module

Tags: 8

I am trying to create a mini-CRUD component on the Drupal 8 site. I am fetching data from an external source, and rendering it using ReactJS.

**I wish to update the database when a user clicks a button in the React component**.

```js
<button
    onClick={() =>
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "../path-to-file/script.php",
            data: { id: 'some data' },
        })}
>
    click me
</button>
```

- I have written the React component (`index.js`),
- I have connected the React component to a custom PHP script with an AJAX script (`script.php`).
- I have written a custom Drupal 8 module to handle the database updates (`mymodule.module`).

However, I can't figure out how to connect the custom PHP script (`script.php`) to the module (`mymodule.module`) to perform the updates.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: It's unclear what you want to do.  When do you want to execute the script?  Find a drupal hook that executes at the desired timing, and use that hook in the module to execute the script.

Comment: Thank you Patrick, I want to execute the script when a user clicks a button. I have updated my question above to include that!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using AJAX to let the user arbitrarily insert data into your database via a custom PHP script seems like a really bad idea because it opens a backdoor into Drupal by circumventing Drupal's security.

To do this the "Drupal" way, you can use the [JSON:API](https://www.drupal.org/docs/core-modules-and-themes/core-modules/jsonapi-module/api-overview) module in core to handle CRUD operations.  This is way too broad a topic to describe in depth here, but [Drupalize.me has a good (paid) tutorial](https://drupalize.me/series/drupal-8-and-reactjs).

This allows you to use JSON:API do CRUD on Drupal entities (nodes, media, taxonomy terms, and so on) using the same access permissions as the Drupal website.

To use this approach, you will need to configure the entities within Drupal so that they receive the data correctly when updated via JSON:API.

Instead of using a custom PHP script, I would create a new [JSON:API Resource](https://www.drupal.org/project/jsonapi_resources), which lets you do whatever kind of processing you want via a custom JSON:API endpoint.  By doing it this way, you get all the data sanitization benefits that are built into Drupal core.